# Is there a thermal sensor technology that can measure an object heat at a distance of 10 meters for Arduino or atmega micro

Tags: sensor, atmega, heat, detection

I am looking for a thermal sensor with a distance of 10 meters . In my plan , I would like to recognize objects based on the heat. for example car.

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific - by recognising objects based on their heat, do you mean image recognition of an infra-red camera, or just 'something warm is between 5 and 15 metres away, I will assume it's a car'

Comment: This exact same question was also posted [here](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8913/is-there-a-thermal-sensor-with-a-distance-of-10-meters-for-arduino). I suggest that you wait a while before you post your question on a second site and that you mention the other question in both places.

Comment: ["Passive infrared" (PIR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_infrared_sensor) may do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An infrared sensor can do this. Just be careful while positioning it to not "see" other hot things. Also, mostly at this distance, will have a wide area of measurement. Search for its DS to check for the angle to calculate its area of "vision". I think will be a good idea to use more than 1 sensor to be more accurate, then you can intercept its measurements to achieve better results.